Flutter ImagePicker choose from gallery keep returns null
I'm using the ImagePIcker library in Flutter to retrieve image from user's phone's gallery. However the result of selection is always null. This only happens when I'm using ImageSource.gallery, it works fine on ImageSource.camera.
I've tried with different data type File or PickedFile but it's still not working.
I'm using version 0.6.7+22 in pubspec.yaml, not sure if this affected, but I've tried with other versions and it still return null.
image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

class SaveImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SaveImageState createState() => _SaveImageState();
}

class _SaveImageState extends State<SaveImage> {
  File _img;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Future cameraImage() async{
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      final img=await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      setState(() {
        _img=File(img.path);
      });
    }
    Future galleryImage() async{
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      // final img=await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      PickedFile img=await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      //the result here always returns null
      print("data: ${img}");
      setState(() {
        _img=File(img.path);
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple[100],
      body: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: img_url,
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
            )
    );
  }
}


I notice you're using quite an old version of image_picker. If there is nothing holding you back I would advice upgrading it to the latest compatible version.
There have been updates to the image picker API as seen here, and by upgrading it might be easier for you to follow along with the documentation.
If upgrading is not an option, I see that the old version of the API says:
PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(...)

which differs from your implementation:
PickedFile img=await ImagePicker.platform.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

Try aligning with the old API, or upgrading the package and see if that helps!
